# Google DataStudio on BigQuery Data, How to display Struct of Arrays

Tags: google-bigquery, looker-studio

I'm trying to display a table in DataStudio plugged on a BigQuery Table. Where I have a String field, and a Struct of 2 Arrays. This is where my issue is.

[image: Table Schema]

When I want to include both of my arrays from the struct, the table kind of time out and shows a connection error. Whereas when I try to include on of them independently there are no issues.

This kind of struct is not supported in DataStudio? Or am I doing something wrong? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't support it. You have to transform it on go in `SELECT` clause.

If you want to concatenate all strings from repeated string field you can use [ARRAY_TO_STRING](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/array_functions#array_to_string):

```
ARRAY_TO_STRING(recos.reco_sku)
```

or for integers, you have to cast them into a string and then concatenate them

```
ARRAY_TO_STRING(
  ARRAY(
    SELECT 
      CAST(i AS STRING) 
    FROM 
      UNNEST(recos.nb_asso) AS i WITH OFFSET o 
    ORDER BY 
      o
  )
)
```

Otherwise, you can explode your array with `LEFT/CROSS JOIN + UNNEST` and make rows flat for each array entry.